# MariaDB REGEXP_REPLACE backreferences not works in FUNCTION

Tags: regex, mariadb, stored-functions, backreference

I have this simple expression:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('aaa 123 bbb 456 ccc', '([0-9]+)', LPAD('\\1', 10, '0'));
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE('aaa 123 bbb 456 ccc', '([0-9]+)', LPAD('\\1', 10, '0')) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| aaa 00000000123 bbb 00000000456 ccc                                     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But if i put this into a FUNCTION:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test()
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
BEGIN
       RETURN REGEXP_REPLACE('aaa 123 bbb 456 ccc', '([0-9]+)', LPAD('\\1', 10, '0'));
END
```

It doesn't works:

```
SELECT test();
+-----------------------------------+
| test()                           |
+-----------------------------------+
| aaa 0000000001 bbb 0000000001 ccc |
+-----------------------------------+
```

How can i fix it? (10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1)

Answer (score 0):

Use `'\1'` instead of `'\\1'`....